# How can I clear ViewModel with jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can I clear ViewModel at certain event? I am using compose navigation.
At the moment when I click 'go back button'. I want to reset the viewModel. But If I check the uiState, when I enter the screen.

1. Prepping -> Idle (which is correct) -> go back
2. (re-enter) Idle -> go back
3. (re-enter) Idle -> go back

I called this function at 'go back event' but it doesn't clear.

```
// ViewModel
fun clear() = viewModelScope.launch {
    onCleared()
}
```

I also tried it with this, but didn't work.

```
DisposableEffect(Unit){
    onDispose {
        viewModel.clear()
    }
}
```

But I shouldn't use this because the data should stay when I go next(not go back) and when the user returns the data should be restored.

Somebody says, I don't need to manage the ViewModel and Navigation does it. But it's not cleared. I am using this for 'go back'

```
navController.navigateToHome(
    navOptions {
        popUpTo(homeGraphRoutePattern)
    }
)
```

Is it wrong?

Comment: `onCleared` is method where your view model can clear some data, it's not used to trigger clear. By default, compose navigation is gonna  clear all view models with dismissed destination - unless you specify parameters. Show code that is used for navigation

Comment: There is no mechanism to reset your view model just by calling a function. You need to write your own function that resets every relevant property and call that. And a tip: any Android or Jetpack function starting with "on" in the name should never be directly called. They are only available for you to override. Calling them (except to call super when overriding them) may cause unexpected behaviors and even crashes.

Comment: Even though you can clear the whole viewModelStore, that will break single source of truth. Since compose still grave the previously cached viewModel until recomposition happen.

Comment: @Watermelon So, How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @c-an implement your own reset

Comment: @EpicPandaForce well, that's too much. That means, it's meaningless to use AAC ViewModel. I need to manually reset all the data in every single ViewModel?, I might miss some data to reset. Or, I need to create my own reflection class for compose ViewModel. And it won't be easy neither.. I updated my question with navigation part. Someone says compose navigation take care of the viewModel. And it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation handles the ViewModel. And the navigation scope of the Screen was wrong.

Before:

```
@Composable
fun MyRoute(
    ...
    moveToOrder: () -> Unit,
    moveToBack: () -> Unit,
    viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel(LocalContext.current as MainActivity),
){
  // content
}
```

After:

```
@Composable
fun MyRoute(
    ...
    moveToOrder: () -> Unit,
    moveToBack: () -> Unit,
    viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
){
  // content
}
```

Comment: Yes, the VM should be scoped to the `LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current`, which is the default.